# akka-http validate file extension on upload

Tags: validation, file-upload, mime-types, akka-http

I need to validate uploaded files against a whitelist of allowed extensions (e.g. `png`, .`pdf` etc) and also check whether the extension corresponds to the real file content in order to avoid malicious files.

For now file upload is done via `fileUpload()` directive that parses file metadata and provides file content as a `Source[ByteString, Any]` which then gets streamed directly to `S3` storage:

```
def uploadFileRoute: Route =
    path("files") {
      post {
          (withSizeLimit(documentSizeLimit) &  fileUpload("file")) {
            case (fileInfo: FileInfo, contentSource: Source[ByteString, Any]) =>
              onSuccess(service.uploadToS3(fileInfo, contentSource)) {
                completeDefault(_)
              }
          }
      }
    }
```

Is there any good solution on how to perform such validation and to keep using the streaming upload (e.g. not to store the whole file locally ) if possible? Any code examples are appreciated!